# Why do parenthesis break my dplyr::filter() output?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I was working through R4DS and learning about the `filter()` function when I came across a strange result. I was trying to `filter` a `tibble` to find only the observations that had a `dep_delay` and a `arr_delay` of less than 2 minutes. Here's my reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
filter(flights, dep_delay & arr_delay < 2)
```

which correctly outputs

```
# A tibble: 187,645 x 19
    year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>
 1  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18
 2  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25
 3  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      709            723       -14
 4  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      838            846        -8
 5  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      849            851        -2
 6  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      853            856        -3
 7  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      923            937       -14
 8  2013     1     1      559            600        -1      854            902        -8
 9  2013     1     1      601            600         1      844            850        -6
10  2013     1     1      602            610        -8      812            820        -8
# ... with 187,635 more rows, and 10 more variables: carrier <chr>, flight <int>,
#   tailnum <chr>, origin <chr>, dest <chr>, air_time <dbl>, distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>,
#   minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>
```

however if I add a parenthesis for some reason the output changes

```
filter(flights, (dep_delay & arr_delay) < 2)
```

```
# A tibble: 327,394 x 19
    year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>
 1  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830            819        11
 2  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850            830        20
 3  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923            850        33
 4  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18
 5  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25
 6  2013     1     1      554            558        -4      740            728        12
 7  2013     1     1      555            600        -5      913            854        19
 8  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      709            723       -14
 9  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      838            846        -8
10  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      753            745         8
# ... with 327,384 more rows, and 10 more variables: carrier <chr>, flight <int>,
#   tailnum <chr>, origin <chr>, dest <chr>, air_time <dbl>, distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>,
#   minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>
```

notice row 2 has incorrect values for both variables. At first I thought perhaps by adding the parenthesis I was converting `(dep_delay & arr_delay)` to `TRUE` or `1` but that actually would create an entirely different output. Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting what you think you're getting.

`dep_delay & arr_delay < 2` is two separate logical conditions.

1. `dep_delay`, which is effectively `(dep_delay != 0)`.
2. `arr_delay > 2`, which is self-evident.

In truth, there are only 167,639 rows in `flights` where `dep_delay` and `arr_delay` are non-`NA` and less than 2.

```r
with(flights, table(arr_delay < 2, dep_delay < 2, useNA = "always")) %>%
  addmargins()
#        
#          FALSE   TRUE   <NA>    Sum
#   FALSE  87941  39988      0 127929
#   TRUE   31778 167639      0 199417
#   <NA>     663    512   8255   9430
#   Sum   120382 208139   8255 336776
```

While I understand what you're trying to do, it does not translate the same into R syntax.

Just do one of:

```r
dplyr::filter(flights, dep_delay < 2 & arr_delay < 2)
dplyr::filter(flights, dep_delay < 2, arr_delay < 2)
```

`dplyr::filter` defaults to an "AND" logic, so you can always use the second format above. Really, the only time you need to start using [`Logic`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) operators is when you want an "OR" anywhere in the logic.

---

BTW: to see more about point 1 above, see

```r
if (-1) 1 else 2
# [1] 1
if (0) 1 else 2
# [1] 2
if (1) 1 else 2
# [1] 1
```

Comment: I still don't understand what my initial command was asking R, however. Is it just purely nonsensical? Because ```filter(flights, dep_delay != 0 | arr_delay > 2)``` gives me 316,375 rows which is less than my initial command. Are those other rows ```N/A```? I understand that my initial command is fundamentally the wrong way to do things, but it's bugging me to not understand what R is thinking.

Comment: `filter` is removing the `NA` values for you. See `table(is.na(filter(flights, dep_delay != 0 | arr_delay > 2)$dep_delay))` versus `table(is.na(flights$dep_delay))` to see that. *"Nonsensical"*? Not really, R interprets it as something, just not as what you intend. There are times when using `if (12)` is fine ... though in truth I find it a little sloppy since there are inferences that *we* make intuitively that R does not.

Comment: `with(flights, table(dep_delay != 0 | arr_delay > 2, useNA = "always"))` shows you the 316375 that `filter` gives you, and explains that 8303 are `NA`, since any logical operation that includes an `NA` (unhandled) is `NA` itself (and not true or false).